# variable keeps being 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database and I am trying to create some sort of an index for each one of my childs - [image]

the index itself does update but under the posts section it keeps being 0, this is the code that is responsible for updating the index

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference indexReference =ref.child("postNum");
indexReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.getValue()==null){
            tempIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            tempIndex =(Long) snapshot.getValue();
            Log.d("read", String.valueOf(tempIndex));
        }
        snapshot.getRef().setValue(tempIndex+1);
        Log.d("temp", String.valueOf(tempIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

this is the code i use to upload new posts to firebase

```
Post post =new Post(etProductName.getText().toString(), date,btChooseLocation.getText().toString(),etProductPrice.getText().toString(),etProductDescription.getText().toString(),uuidImage,uid, tempIndex);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(uuidPost).setValue(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your reference to postNum inside Posts table is wrong. You need to change it to `ref.child("Posts").child(PostID).child("postNum");`

Comment: @Shmebulouk Don't post large blocks of additional code in comments please. Instead edit your question (there's a link under it), and add this code there.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution might help you

```
Post post =new Post(etProductName.getText().toString(),date ,btChooseLocation.getText().toString(), etProductPrice.getText().toString(), etProductDescription.getText().toString(), uuidImage, uid, tempIndex);
    
//Before setting, check your POST object by printing it
//ref.child("Posts").child(yourPostID).setValue(post);

ref.child("Posts").child("a1d03799-6146-4776-9d69-73b8d9d7ae61").setValue(post);
```